# CSS changes doesn't appear

Tags: css

I'm trying to change the color of my menu and address on the top of the website. But the color wont change.

I already found the style.css file in the theme/css/style.css. I changed this in the code and uploaded to my filezilla. But it seems there is something what overwrites my code.

This is what appears

```
    .navbar-white .brand,
.navbar-white .brand:hover,
.navbar-white .brand:focus,
.navbar-white .brand-text,
.navbar-white .navbar-address,
.navbar-white .navbar-address .text-dark,
.navbar-white .social-list a{
  color: #fff; 
}
```

And it should be

```
.navbar-white .brand,
.navbar-white .brand:hover,
.navbar-white .brand:focus,
.navbar-white .brand-text,
.navbar-white .navbar-address,
.navbar-white .navbar-address .text-dark,
.navbar-white .social-list a{
  color: #000; 
}
```

I hope i can get them all black on the front page. So my background wont overflow my menu button.

Comment: Try using ctrl+F5 to refresh the page instead of just F5

Comment: can you try important ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static file changes not reflected in served stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47497207/static-file-changes-not-reflected-in-served-stylesheet)

Comment: @NishargShah — don't use `!important` ... it was meant to be used on the _client_ side so users viewing a website could override styles (such as increasing contrast if they don't see well). `!important` used on the server side is a crutch to fix otherwise broken styles; instead of using important, fix the underlying problems, which are usually from being too specific or not specific enough in your selectors.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your browser has saved the stylesheet in the browser cache. Try emptying the cache.

Generally, it is good practice to let everyone know that you updated your stylesheet by using syntax like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css?v=2">` (note the `v=2` indicating the stylesheet version) in your embed (as other visitors who may not have emptied their cache could still get the old stylesheet).

For local development, I like to use Plugins like *LiveReload* for Chrome, which completely reloads the page whenever a change is saved to a file in a specified folder.

Comment: Also, by adding the changing variable after the '?' it becomes a new address so will not have a cached version.